# Link-cut trees: how to code cut(u,v)

Tags: data-structures, trees, search-trees, balanced-search-trees

In most bibliography, only cut(v) is defined.
More properly, only cut(v,v.parent) is defined, where (v,v.parent) is an edge in the represented tree.

The pseudo-code and code for this is:

```
cut(x):
   access(x);
   parent(left(x)) = null
   left(x) = null

void cut(Node *x){
   access(x);
   x->left->parent = 0;
   x->left = 0;
}
```

> How can we define cut(u,v) for an arbitrary (u,v)?
>
> I.e. how can we code cut(u,v) in such a way that
>
> 1. If (u,v) is not an edge in the represented tree, then do nothing;
> 2. If (u,v) is an edge of the represented tree, cut the edge in the represented tree.

The following function may help, it determines the root of the represented tree that contains the node x.

```
root(x):
   access(x)
   while(left(x) =/= null)
      x = left(x)
   splay(x)

LCT *root(LCT *x){
   access(x);
   while((*x).left != NULL){
       x = (*x).left;
   }
   splay(x);
   return x;
}
```

Additional reference (code): https://github.com/saadtaame/link-cut-tree

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand what your question is.  If you are asking how to make a mathematical definition of cut(u,v), you can define a term in any way you want.  Only you can tell us what definition you want to use.  If your question is about how to implement something in C code, that is off-topic here.  Coding questions and programming questions are off-topic here, so we ask that you eliminate all C code and replace it with concise pseudocode and ideas.

Comment: First of all, how to determine if a pair (u,v) is an edge of the represented tree. And if it is the case, how to cut this edge. Here code and pseudo-code are essentially the same

Comment: I don't think you should assume that everyone here reads C code. We already have a separate site (Stack Overflow) for implementation questions and questions about code.

Answer (score 2):

The function $cut(v)$ is only defined for cutting $v$ from its parent for a reason, because this is the **only** possibility. The *represented tree* is first and foremost a [**Tree**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure)#Definition). By definition, edges will only exist from a parent to a child. Therefore, the only edge you would ever need to cut is from parent to child.